# Handling of Exceptions in anti-corruption layer (ACL)

Tags: exception, domain-driven-design

What are the recommended practices when writing an anti-corruption layer in regards to exceptions?

Is it fair to say that exceptions should be wrapped/shielded as any other interface aspects of the system (aka bounded context) getting integrated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An anti-corruption layer is here to prevent idioms and behavior of an external system from leaking into your Bounded Context. Therefore, it seems a good idea to wrap exceptions that come out of it into ones that make sense for your BC.

Doing this also forces you to think about the error cases that could happen inside the anticorruption layer and make your application more robust. By the way, not all errors happening inside the ACL can/will be caused by direct third party system client exceptions. You also have to address successful but incoherent results, errors signalled in another way than exceptions (like unexpected HTTP response statuses), etc.

Note that wrapping the exception doesn't mean truncating it - we need to preserve all the information from the original error. All good practices around exceptions remain valid.

Answer (score 0):

I don't wrap all of those exceptions. I can let the legacy exceptions bubble up the stack. Reason being it can clutter your anti-corruption layer. But it depends sometimes because there might be requirements to return error codes for certain exceptions. Those exceptions I wrap to my new bounded context (the anti-corruption layer).